# How to Maintain Landing pages with shared components from the main site while keeping them independent?

Tags: javascript, frontend, bundler, webpack-5, npm-package

I am trying to find a better approach on creating and maintaining landing pages along site a  large CMS built with Laravel(5.8 + mix 6).

Ideally, the landing pages should be able to use main site assets and components when are build but should not be affected by any changes made afterwards BUT we should be able to propagate wanted changes to specific components without updating all of them.

Our current setup is the following:

- in public we have an `lp` folder with multiple sub directories for each landing page
- each lp page has a plain index.php that stores the html
- we copy the main site **bundled** assets in each landing page directory and load it from there
- in the event of a global change we need to propagate we would recompile the main bundle and copy it again in each landing page and kinda pray not too many break.

Current file structure:

```
.
└── public/
    ├── dist/ #main site bundle
    │   ├── style
    │   └── scripts
    └── lp/
        ├── lp-slug-1
        ├── lp-slug-2
        └── lp-slug-3/
            ├── dist #copied main site bundle 
            └── index.php
```

Comment: what about using Blade templates to embed shared components ? for dynamic rendering and maintaining individuality of pages and implement dynamic routing to serve different content with a single template for example.

Comment: sounds like you need to push your javascript components out to a package repository, then you can version them.

Comment: @lopm46 I don't think that really fixes any of the problems I am trying to solve. Could you expand on this comment maybe I am missing the point.

Comment: @danielRicado that is a solution we thought about but I don't really have experience with maintaining packages. Even if we do end up moving the components to their own repo I guess I would need to create multiple packages for each plugin we need to keep separate right?

Comment: no idea the complexity of your project, but the basics would be to prepare the components in a state your landing pages will use, and lock a specific version for your landing pages to use. You can then continue development of the components and the locked versions aren't impacted next time you release. publishing to npm is pretty stright forward and lots of good tutorials around to help.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I ended up solving this issue is by moving all the assets in a npm package.
We also moved the project to yarn and made use of the yarn work spaces to develop the ui and lps while keeping their dependencies separate.

I ended up creating a quick pipeline to publish the package in our private registry.

One challenge that I faced was preventing yarn to resolve the package to his local (workspace version). The way I fixed it was by preventing hoisting of the packages past their workspace.

Overall a good solution, will update if we encounter issues in the future.